# Android SQLiteOpenHelper : SOPL from onCreate() method not shown

Tags: android

im trying to do a system.out.println("something") inside onCreate() for SQLiteOpenHelper. but i didn't get anything. i even made sure to call getReadableDatabase();

anyone knows why?

this is my sqlite class

```
public class ChatOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";
private static final String CHAT_TABLE_NAME = "Bolster_ME_YOU";
private static final String CHAT_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + CHAT_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                " test VARCHAR(255) );";
private static final String CHAT_TABLE_DELETE =
        "DROP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + CHAT_TABLE_NAME + ");";

public ChatOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    System.out.println("hello from sqlite");
    System.out.println(this.getDatabaseName());
    db.execSQL(CHAT_TABLE_DELETE);
    db.execSQL(CHAT_TABLE_CREATE);
    Log.v("smartdbhelper", "after creation");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    this.onCreate(db);
}
}
```

//this is the activity class

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button signin;
private Button signup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    signin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_signin);
    signup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_signup);


    ChatOpenHelper open = new ChatOpenHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sql = open.getReadableDatabase();
    sql.close();
    open.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use System.out.print(), Use Log.d("value", "value");

Comment: i tried that as well but nothing is shown. see my code

Comment: Try using Log.d() instead of Log.v()

Comment: still nothing is shown

Comment: Look at this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase) 
`onCreate()` only called once when application is installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate() is only called when the database is created for the first time.
2. You'd better use Log.d("label", "value") rather than System.out.print().

Comment: i tried Log.d Log.v but still nothing. i dont know why ppl are always commenting on SOPL when for me its working totally fine.

Comment: My second advice is not the point. I think the onCreate() is not called. Uninstall your app and try again, so the database is created for the first time. Then check if onCreate() is called.

Comment: thanks, the uninstalling shows the log. but i need to know why. seems that onCreate() is only called once? i tried changing the table name to see if creating a different table could enable it. but it doesnt work.

Comment: Yes, onCreate() is only called once. If you only change the table name, onCreate() won't be called again, unless you change your DATABASE_NAME.

Comment: In other words, if the DATABASE_NAME has changed or there's no database file with the same name of DATABASE_NAME, onCreate() will be called; if DATABASE_VERSION has increased, onUpgrade() will be called.